# Failed to start video surface due to main thread blocked error in QML

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qml, webcam, qt5

I wrote a sample QML- qt5 application for webcam display giving an Error :
OS:UBUNTU 13.04
Qt Creator 2.7.1 Based on Qt 5.0.2 (64 bit)

```
Failed to start video surface due to main thread blocked. 
Failed to start video surface 
CameraBin error: "Internal data flow error."
```

PS: This error occurs randomly and most of the times; let say 18-19 times in 20 times

Here is the code :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtMultimedia 5.0

Item {
width: 320
height: 240

VideoOutput {
    id:camOutput
    source: camera
    anchors.fill: parent
    focus : visible // to receive focus and capture key events when visible

}

Camera {
    id: camera

    imageProcessing.whiteBalanceMode: CameraImageProcessing.WhiteBalanceFlash

    exposure {
        exposureCompensation: -1.0
        exposureMode: Camera.ExposurePortrait
    }

    flash.mode: Camera.FlashRedEyeReduction

    imageCapture {
        onImageCaptured: {
            photoPreview.source = preview  // Show the preview in an Image
        }
    }

}
Image {
    id: photoPreview
}
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Do you found any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is a bug in Qt- see [QTBUG-39567](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-39567).

When writing this post (June 2017) there is no actual solution, but workaround is suggested:

*Do not play video immediately when starting your app- wait one second on more before starting your video player.*

I have tested this and it fixed my problem with playing video.

In your case this is not a video player but in my opinion this is related to all `QtMultimedia` components.